# Compute percentage change by increasing window size up to period

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, percentage

Say I have this series

```
s = pd.Series([90, 91, 85, 95])
```

If I compute the [percentage change](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pct_change.html) with a period of 2 I get

```
s.pct_change(periods=2)

0         NaN
1         NaN
2   -0.055556
3    0.043956
dtype: float64
```

But say I have a couple of years of data and I want to compute the year over year (YoY) rolling returns, with `pct_change(365)`. Then I would loose a year's worth of data (in the sense that I have 365 NaN values before I have a valid observation).

**I would instead like to compromise by starting as if I had a period of 1, 2, then 3 and so on up until I reach the specified** `periods`.

In other words, I would like an output of the likes of

```
0         NaN
1    0.011111
2   -0.055556
3    0.043956
dtype: float64
```

or

```
0           0
1    0.011111
2   -0.055556
3    0.043956
dtype: float64
```

Is this possible? I know that [pandas.DataFrame.rolling](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html) has basically this functionality with the argument `min_periods`, but I couldn't find something similar for [pandas.DataFrame.pct_change](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pct_change.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [numpy](/questions/tagged/numpy) and its [`sliding_window_view`](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/generated/numpy.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view.html):

```
from numpy.lib.stride_tricks import sliding_window_view as swv

N = 2

v = swv(np.pad(s, (N, 0), constant_values=s.iloc[0]), N+1)

out = pd.Series((v[:, -1]-v[:, 0])/v[:, 0], index=s.index)
```

Output:

```
0    0.000000
1    0.011111
2   -0.055556
3    0.043956
dtype: float64
```

With pandas, it looks like a [`rolling`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.window.rolling.Rolling.apply.html) in which you use the first and last value of the window:

```
N = 2

s.rolling(N+1, min_periods=0).apply(lambda x: (x.iloc[-1]-x.iloc[0])/x.iloc[0])
```

Output:

```
0    0.000000
1    0.011111
2   -0.055556
3    0.043956
dtype: float64
```